# Create a new column with sum of few other columns in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I want to add a column which will contain summation of some columns.

Basically I want to convert following:

[image]

to the following:

[image]

But this has to be done dynamically i.e. I shall provide colModel id of th e columns I want the summation of.

P.S. Using 4.13.5 version of free-jqgrid.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve the problem, but the best choice depend on other details. Which `datatype` you use? Do you need to edit the data? What other features you need to use in the column "All" (sorting, searching, ...)?

Comment: @Oleg datatype is default.I supply array data to data key of jqgrid object.Edit data not required.Sorting/searching is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to implement your requirements would be the usage of `jsonmap` and `sorttype` defined as function, which returns the calculated value of the column. Additionally you would need to implement `afterSetRow` callback, which fixes the value after modification the row (after `setRowData`).

The corresponding implementation could be like in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-calculatedColumn.htm). The demo defines the grid with `total` column, which displays the sum of `amount` and `tax` columns. The code of the demo looks as following:

```js
var calculateTotal = function (item) {
        return parseFloat(item.amount) + parseFloat(item.tax);
    };

$("#list").jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel: [
        ...
        { name: "amount", template: "number", ... },
        { name: "tax", template: "number", ... },
        { name: "total", width: 76, template: "number", editable: false,
            jsonmap: function (item) {
                return calculateTotal(item);
            },
            sorttype: function (cellValue, item) {
                return calculateTotal(item);
            }},
        ...
    ],
    afterSetRow: function (options) {
        var item = options.inputData;
        if (item.total === undefined) {
            // test is required to prevent recursion
            $(this).jqGrid("setRowData", options.rowid, {
                total: calculateTotal(item)
            });
        }
    }
    ...
});
```